# When declare collection type column in Entity, difference instance or none

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

```java
@OneToMany
List<Something> list;

@OneToMany
List<Something> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

In `Èntity`, people are declaring in two ways, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spring Data/JPA always makes sure to return a non-null collection.** I think this is because to reduce NULL check needed if it return NULL instead of Empty collection.

So it is a good hygiene to maintain a non-null collection for instead of null. At it works well when you unit test these entities, no need to bother when nothing comes from the database.

Moreover take a look at spring documentation says for [Null Handling for repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.nullability)